# Copy Content From One File to Another File in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I need to do the following:

1. create x.txt
2. then put 4 words(i have two kids) in create x.txt
3. output (i have two kids) in result.txt

Only number 3 should be created in batch file.

[image: Files in Folder]

[image: code in me.bat]

Comment: Do you want to append or replace the content in the result.txt

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam. Hi! the result.txt is empty. Just put the two "append" and "replace". Thanks

Comment: So you basically want to copy a file, right? Anyway, please post text as such rather than as images!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a content of a file in another file you can use `type` command to display the content and `>` to redirect the output to a file.

```
@type x.txt > results.txt
```

Note: If you want to append instead of replace the content use `>>` instead of `>` so the command will be `@type x.txt >> results.txt`

Comment: Thank you. What about not using the "type". Is there other way to do it?. Its ok if its a bit long. Thanks

Comment: You could just us copy command like `@copy x.txt results.txt`. `type` is an internal command i.e. the command is part of cmd.exe no other software need to be installed.

Comment: ok. thats ok. one last thing. Can you help me out? I want to output the result in reverse. I have "i have two kids". I want to output it "kids two have i". Thanks

Comment: @Joseph that's bit complicated ask a new question. i'll try to answer it.

Comment: Hello. Can you put it here. they closed my question? Thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I'm trying once I got it i'll

Comment: You can just put it here. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph check https://gist.github.com/seenukarthi/f9b49cc4f4df202992a1d9a2c8d52741

Comment: I'm very sorry i forgot to tell you, I'm not allowed to use loop. I'm so sorry. If its ok you change it. Its also ok if it not. Thank you so much

Comment: Hmm, I'm not expert in batch script. If you find the solution without loop please share it with me.